# Interpolation of inconsisten Data using Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I started working with Simulink and struggeling with the following problem:

I have a time vector
timeVec = [0 1 2 3 3.5 4.2 5.5 7 8];
and a data vector
dataVec = rand(length(timeVec),1)*5+2;

What I need is a Simulink model which interpolates the 'dataVec' Vector based on the simulation time steps, speaking from 0 to 8 in 0.1 intervals.

I did reproduce the example of the documentation (see https://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/interpolation.html) but it was not yet possible for me to solve my problem. Am I a least using the correct block? The Vector 'dataVec' in Simulink is given by a constant source block.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [1D Lookup Table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/1dlookuptable.html), where your `dataVec` and `timeVec` are the appropriate block parameters.  You can use any of several blocks as an input signal, including [Clock](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/clock.html) or [Ramp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/ramp.html), depending on other requirements such as do you need to generate code from the model, and/or what solvers settings you are using.